# child routes not routing to content page in angular 5

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular-routing

i have created many modules which has internal components

folder strutcure

```
--app
      --java
        --Introduction
         --Syntax
```

each of them is a component , and i have added routing module to all components .

now if i add children route to app.routing.ts , it is routing correctly.
but when i add child routes to different routing module ,it does not route to that component
and gives error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'JAVACourse/Syntax'
```

following below are some of my codes :

1.app.routing.ts

i have commented the children routes as this is working.

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path:'Home' , component: HomepageComponent },
{path:'JAVACourse' , component: JavaComponentComponent },
// children: [
//   { path:  'Introduction',component:IntroductionComponent},
//            { path: 'Syntax', component: SyntaxComponent },
//   ]
// }

{path:'HTMLCourse' , component: HtmlcomponentComponent },
{path:'ASP.NET' , component: DotnetcomponentComponent },
// {path: '', redirectTo: '/Home',pathMatch: 'full'},
 //{path: '**',redirectTo: '/Home',pathMatch: 'full'  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
```

In my main component i have many  horizontal navbar tab i.e Java Tab which routes to sidenavbar with child tabs.

2.javacomponent.html

```
<ul>
      <a>JAVA Course</a>
      <li routerLinkActive="active"[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"><a routerLink="Introduction">Introduction</a></li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="Syntax">Syntax</a></li>


</ul>
```

3. java.routing.ts

   ```
   const JavaRoutes: Routes = [
     {path:'JAVACourse' , component: JavaComponentComponent ,
    children: [
      { path:  'Introduction',component:IntroductionComponent},
      { path: 'Syntax', component: SyntaxComponent }
     ]}
   ```

   ];

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       RouterModule.forChild(JavaRoutes)
     ],
     exports: [
       RouterModule
     ]
   })

4.Java.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    JavaRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    IntroductionComponent,
    SyntaxComponent
  ],
  providers: [ ]
})
export class JavaRoutingModule {}
```

[So this my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeZUO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use loadChildren for load lazy modules like.

I have created a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be7egd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts). I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> app.module.ts

```
const app_routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/java',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }, {
        path: 'java',
        component:JavaModule
    },{
        path: 'php',
        loadChildren: () => PhpModule
    }
];
```

> java.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'java',
        component: JavaDashboardComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'introduction',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },{
                path: 'introduction',
                component: JavaIntroductionComponent
            },{
                path: 'syntax',
                component: JavaSyntaxComponent
            },{
                path: 'java-script',
                component: JavaScriptComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . i was not importing javarouting module to module.ts correctly. it worked .

Answer (score 0):

In your **app.routing.ts**, instead of using

`{path:'JAVACourse' , component: JavaComponentComponent },`

use

`{ 'path': 'JAVACourse', loadChildren: './java/java.module#JavaModule' },`.

Also replace

`{path:'JAVACourse' , component: JavaComponentComponent ,`

with

`{path:'' , component: JavaComponentComponent ,`

in **java.routing.ts**. Assuming JavaModule is the module name that is inside java folder.

Comment: Thanks , i tries it , but still it does not route to side navbar now. it give me error as  : Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'JavaComponent' in './java-component/java.module'. i have edited my question with an image . please let me know if i am addinf correct LoadChildren .

Answer (score 0):

You can also use loadChildren for load lazy modules like.

```
{path:"lazy", loadChildren: () => CustomersModule}
```

I have created a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-loading-is-not-working-for-angular-4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts). I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

Comment: I need to add child routes in lazy loading . i guess there is some error in JavaModule.

Comment: Okay I will create demo for  child routes in lazy loading